# C++ question: why don't brace-enclosed initialiser lists work inside classes?

Tags: c++

Simple program to demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

//class MyClass
//{
//public:
    void initTest (std::vector< std::function<bool()> > funcVec)
    {
        for (auto func : funcVec);
    }

    bool a () { return true; }
    bool b () { return false; }
    bool c () { return false; }

    void test ()
    {
        initTest({a, b, c});
    }
//};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

As written it compiles with no errors, but if you uncomment the class definition it won't compile at all. The error message claims "no known conversion from brace-enclosed initialiser list to vector of functions", but clearly there is, as outside the class it works just fine.

Can someone explain what the error is and (if posssible) give a solution? Many thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with initialiser lists. You should make a [mcve] before posting (i.e. debug before posting) so that you are asking the right question. Yours is [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/039753a4b834279e).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the type of the member functions `a`, `b` and `c` is not convertible to `std::function<bool()>` anymore. This is also explained by the fact, that member functions have to be called on an object; this fact has to be reflected in the type.

However, if you were to provide the argument `this` to the member function, you could use the existing interface

```cpp
      initTest({std::bind(&MyClass::a, this), std::bind(&MyClass::b, this),
                std::bind(&MyClass::c, this)});
```

You could also change the type of the `std::map` if you for instance would like to store only member functions in it. 
The aforementioned adaptation to your code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xUqmBB) on Compiler explorer.

Comment: *"a, b and c is not `std::function<bool()>` anymore"*. it was not before neither ;-) but convertible to.

Answer (score 0):

Bascially as mutableVoid already said, the problem is you are now trying to pass a member function to `initTest` and that cannot be converted to an `std::function<bool()>`

Two alternative ways to what he said could be

Option 1:

> Make `a()`, `b()` and `c()` static functions. (Would be the easiest, but obviously only works if you don't need to access the instance itself)

Option 2:

> You could wrap the calls to `a()`, `b()` and `c()` in lambda functions that keep a reference to `this` like so:

```cpp
initTest({ [this](){return a();}, [this](){return b();}, [this](){return c();} });
```